# Communication between objects with IOLoop

Tags: tornado

I want to run a `TCPServer` and a `tornado.web.Application` within the same IOLoop. I want to use the TCPServer to handle IPC. I initialise everything the usual way:

```
   tcpServer = TCPServer()
   tcpServer.listen(8888,address="127.0.0.1")


   tornado.options.parse_command_line()
   app=Application()

   server=tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(app)
   server.listen(8000)
   tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().start()
```

How can I make a call within the `tornado.web.Application` to invoke TCPServer methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass TCPServer instance to Application (even create it within). Below simple example with handler:

```
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.httpserver
import tornado.options
from tornado.web import RequestHandler, Application
from tornado.tcpserver import TCPServer

tcpServer = TCPServer()
tcpServer.listen(8888,address="127.0.0.1")


class MainHandler(RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        if self.request.uri == '/stop':
            self.write("tcpserver stopped")
            self.application.tcp_server.stop()
        else:
            self.write("go to /stop tcpserver")


class CustomApp(Application):

    def __init__(self, tcp_server, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CustomApp, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.tcp_server = tcp_server
        # self.tcp_server.some_method...
        self.add_handlers(r"^.*$", [(r"/.*", MainHandler)])

tornado.options.parse_command_line()
app=CustomApp(tcpServer)

server=tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(app)
server.listen(8000)
tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().start()
```

If you need to call that server via TCP from Application, not the logic directly, you can use TCPClient.

Comment: thanks mate, for some reason i didn't think about putting it there. I thought it might need get missed by the IOLoop...

Comment: In single-threaded (recommended) apps, every action (asynchonous) share the same IOLoop to wait/resolve.